# How do I start my rMBP fans BEFORE login?

Tags: crash, startup, temperature

My rMBP late 2013, 15 inch, running Mojave 10.14, has some issues with the graphics card overheating. Once I'm logged in and have Macs Fan Control running, it's fairly stable unless I run some GPU heavy game or something (at which point the screen goes dark, the fans are still running so the computer is still on, and I have to hold the power button to close it). But when initially logging in on startup, the fans don't run, and it gets really hot, often crashing before I get to log in at all.

Is there a way I can get Macs Fan Control or smcfancontrol to turn on my fans BEFORE I log in?

Also, in case this matters, I DO have Filevault on, AFAIK that encrypts the hard disk until you're logged in so that might make it harder (I tried playing with making a LaunchDaemon to open MacsFanControl but then I couldn't log in at all and had to go into Safe Boot to undo that change).

Comment: A different solution: have you tried reapplying the thermal paste? It might give you a enough thermal headroom to log in and open fan control.

Comment: Reapplying the thermal paste and cleaning the dust out of the case might work

Comment: There are methods of disabling the discrete GPU, often used to fix issues of this sort. (Of which there are many in MBPs.) I don't know if the setting takes effect from early boot.
   
However, software fixes for hardware issues are sub-optimal and temporary at best. Given that it's a defective 8-year-old Mac, and won't be supported by Monterey, I'd 'call it'.